# Porting LibPBC to Native Client?

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I want to develop an extension using the [PBC library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/). The amount and quality of documentation on doing this for Firefox's XPCOM was rather obscure, and Native Client seems interesting to experiment with.

In order to port the library, I changed the config and Makefile according to [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient-sdk/wiki/HowTo_PortCode). It does (obviously) require to remove dependencies on shared libraries. I thus need to also build the GMP library with the nacl-toolchain and then reference from pbc.

Comment: have you been able to port pbc? if yes can you please share your result with me? I'm having trouble when porting pbc also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with libPBC but I know gmp can be built for nacl. If you set your CC environment variable to the nacl compiler and run configure with 
--host=none-pc-nacl you will get a generic C-only build of gmp which doesn't use the assembly code (gmp's assembly code is not nacl-safe).

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. Meanwhile, I have already managed to compile GMP and PBC for Native Client. For the steps required for GMP configuration, I've created a gist here: https://gist.github.com/1380547  .. However, as you're answer describes the correct steps, I'll tick it as the solution :)